# Jquery to show <div> class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using google maps API to show duration between 2 addresses, using this code.

```
function addresses(froma, toa) {
       var starting_location = froma;
    var end_location = toa;

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [starting_location],
            destinations: [end_location],
            travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        }, callback);

    function callback(response, status) {

        $(".results").text("Duration: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text);

    }
}
```

The problem i'm facing is, i have a while loop which shows client data row by row. In one column i have

```
<div class="results"></div>
```

and using jquery i am trying to show every row with its own data of duration time, using the callback

```
$(".results").text("Duration: " +
               response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text);
```

This inturn is showing all the columns with the same values. How to show each column with its own unique data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can see your json?

Comment: you should get length of data and get every data in "while" or "for"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps use something like the following callback to iterate over the results and append them to the output div:

```
function callback(response, status) {

    $.each(response.rows, function( index, row ) {

        $(".results").append("Duration: " + row.elements[0].duration.text + "<br>");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a guess here, but most likely you have a `<div class="results"></div>` element in each row of your view. So, when you are doing a jQuery selector `.results` that code is applied to all the divs with a class 'results'.

Either you can use a unique id as jQuery selector or you can limit the scope of the selector (something like `$(rowElement).find('.results').text(....)`).

Again, this is just my guess. If you can share the while loop code and the DOM structure, we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each `rows` and there given `elements` to find each trip info. JSON format taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix). I assume it's similar to this:

```
{
  "originAddresses": [ "Greenwich, Greater London, UK", "13 Great Carleton Square, Edinburgh, City of Edinburgh EH16 4, UK" ],
  "destinationAddresses": [ "Stockholm County, Sweden", "Dlouhá 609/2, 110 00 Praha-Staré Město, Česká republika" ],
  "rows": [ {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 70778,
        "text": "19 hours 40 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1887508,
        "text": "1173 mi"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 44476,
        "text": "12 hours 21 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1262780,
        "text": "785 mi"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 96000,
        "text": "1 day 3 hours"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 2566737,
        "text": "1595 mi"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 69698,
        "text": "19 hours 22 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1942009,
        "text": "1207 mi"
      }
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

You can do something like this:

```
function callback(response, status) {
    var div = $('<div></div>');

    response.rows.foreach(function(row, index) {
        div.append('<div>Trip: ' + (index + 1) + '</div>');
        row.elements.foreach(function(element) {
            var duration = $('<div>Duration: ' + element.duration.text + '</div>');
            div.append(duration);
        });
    });

    $(".results").append('<div>From: ' + response.originAddresses + '</div>');
    $(".results").append('<div>To: ' + response.destinationAddresses + '</div>');
    $(".results").append(div);

}
```

The output would be something like this:

```
<div class="results">
    <div>From: Source Address</div>
    <div>To: Destination</div>
    <div> <!-- Repeat this block for each row in response.rows -->
        <div>Trip 1</div>
        <div>Duration: 19 hours 40 mins</div>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
</div>
```